# Xamarin.Forms - Update label text with a timer doesn't work on Windows Phone

Tags: xamarin.forms

First thing: I'm sorry for my english! Please forgive me!

On my Xamarin Forms project I need to create a kind of speedometer, with a gauge and a label. It must be animated, so when I click the start button, I create a timer and every time it's expired I change the image's rotation and I update the text label's property. In this way, I see the numbers increasing in parallel with the image movement.
I had to use a relative layout because the label is above the image and the image is realy more overlapping images and there's a StackLayout to cover the lower part.

It works perfectly on Android and iOS, but on WinPhone... the image rotate but the label remain on 0. If I start it again, the label change the value to the last previous value. It seems it cannot update realtime.

I tried to put the label update in a blank project (without images) and it works, so the code is correct.

I tried various force layout, raise child.. but without success. On WinPhone I had to remove and put  again the layout with label and the cover layout to keep them in front after load the iamges because the Raise Child function doesn't work (There's another way?).

At the bottom there's a link for a demo project where I've extracted the part of code incriminated. I don't know why, but this project on Android moves jerkily, doesn't have a fluid movement. The code is the same, the images are the same... I'm going crazy!!

What's my mistake? There's something I forget? Any idea about what can I do?

Thanks

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wuh04z12mat9bxk/DemoGaugeNew.zip?dl=0

Comment: please do NOT post code as an external link - it's not indexable by search engines, and when the link expires this question will become useless for anyone who finds it in the future.  Take the time to post the *relevant* portions of your code, properly formatted, into the body of the question.

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake, but the code have a lot of files whit a lot of lines for each one! I don't have a specific error point unfortunaly!